# Maven: Profile activation depending on localRepository property?

Tags: maven, profile, activation, pom.xml

in Maven I want to execute a build only if the artifact has not yet been installed to the repository. My idea is to use a profile which is inactive by default, but will be activated if the artifact is missing.
So far I was not successful because it seems that Maven properties cannot be used for profile activation?

settings.xml:

```
...
<localRepository>/local/m2repo</localRepository>
...
```

1) This works:

pom.xml:

```
...
<profile>
    <id>my-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <file>
            <missing>/local/m2repo/something</missing>
        </file>
    </activation>
    ...
</profile>
```

2) This doesn't work:

pom.xml:

```
...
<profile>
    <id>my-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <file>
            <missing>${settings.localRepository}/something</missing>
        </file>
    </activation>
    ...
</profile>
```

3) This won't work either:

settings.xml:

```
...
<properties>
    <local.repository>${settings.localRepository}</local.repository>
</properties>
...
```

pom.xml:

```
<profile>
    <id>my-profile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <file>
            <missing>${local.repository}/something</missing>
        </file>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Is there somehow a workaround or alternative how I can check for the existence of my artifact and only run a build if necessary?
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

The activation file location normally are relative to the current project folder.

The properties will be calculated only after the profiles are already defined and build started.